# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24

Tags: android, xml, inflate-exception

i have a xml file which i am trying to use in custom `ListView`.
The `xml` file looks like below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    android:textSize="25dp" 
    android:gravity="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:baseline="@id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/offline" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

i am inflating it with my custom listview but it is showing error inflateException

```
  02-28 15:50:08.363: E/AndroidRuntime(19777): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Comment: Post full xml code. And, what is on line number 24

Comment: post your proper code that how you are inflating your xml in your custom adapter. Then one can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your children in proper container like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/realtivelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/offline" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 android:baseline="@id/imageView1"
```

`android:baseline` wants a dimension

From the doc:

> The offset of the baseline within this view. [dimension]